# How do I populate a column with the first x characters of text data in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, extract, string

I have a column with 14 characters.  There is real information based on the first three characters.  I want to have another column with only the first three characters for visibility and group by functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Left` function in Excel.

i.e. `=Left(A1,3)` where `A1` contains the 14 character data and 3 is the number of characters from the left to display.

Copy the cell with the function down.  It will display the first three characters for each cell.